# NIB Name Unchanged Using xcode refactor

Tags: ios, xcode, xib, nib

I have used xcode refactor to change the name of a ViewController.  I highlighted the controller name in the .h file, then used Edit>Refactor>Rename.  Everything was changed correctly, including the name of the .xib file.  However when I go to load the nib with initWithNibName: the new name is not recognized.   I must still provide the string value of the old name of the controller.

I have tried searching for the old name in the .xib file, using an XML editor, in the hopes of changing it there.  With no luck.

Does anyone know how I can change the nib name so it matches the new file name of the .xib file?

[ I'm using xcode 4.2 ]

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project?

Answer (score 1):

XCode will not change calls to initWithNibName that use a literal string (for example `initWithNibName:@"FooViewController withBundle:nil]`).  This is one of the reasons I tend to code like this:  `initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([FooViewController class]) withBundle:nil` so look in your code for any calls that use literal strings.

**QUICK EDIT:** But it occurs to me that you may have already changed it manually.  In that case do a quick project uninstall and clean.

Comment: Calling `NSStringFromClass` manually is not needed. If you want to load the nib with the same name as your class you can use `nil` for the nib name.

Comment: Yes, you could also do this, but occasionally it doesn't work right for me...I don't know why ><

Comment: Your quick edit gets to the root of my problem.  If I change the string literal to the new nib name I get a failure in initWithName.  I have reinstalled and cleaned to no avail.  Indicating that somewhere the old name is still being used for the nib.  Where that old name is stored is a mystery.  However I have taken Sven's advice and used nil for the nib name in initWithNibName: and it works fine.  I didn't know you could do that!  So the old name is still buried somewhere, but I won't worry about it since it doesn't show in my code.